# Java normal distribution

Tags: java, random, normal-distribution

I'm trying to simulate the arrival of fans to a stadium. The system itself, I believe it won't be a problem, but, the arrival of the fans follows a normal distribution.

My problem is:

I have a certain time for the arrival like 100 minutes and 1000 fans, and I need to generate arrivals of Fans at a time following that distribution like -> fan x arrived at 25 minutes, fan y arrived at 54 minutes, and so on.

How can I generate these random numbers following a normal distribution?

I'm doing this in Java and found the `nextGaussian()` method in the [Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Random.html), but I'm not sure how to use this in my situation.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Watch out.  Are you sure you want a normal distribution?  Normally you'd expect interarrival times to have an *exponential* distribution...

Comment: In this case is believed to be a normal distribution, and I was told to do this study in that way. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`nextGaussian()` will draw samples from a normal distribution with mean 0 and std-deviation 1, so if you want mean 1 hour and std-deviation 15 minutes you'll need to call it as `nextGaussian()*15+60`.

From the [docs for `Random.nextGaussian()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian--):

> Returns:
>   the next pseudorandom, Gaussian ("normally") distributed double value with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you to use apache math: http://commons.apache.org/math/ , look here for more information: http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html